# How to add item in array?

Tags: java, arrays

I want add item at the top of array?

how can i achieve this?

there are two item in array. i want to add item at top of the array.

```
result1 = new String[result.length+1];

            for(int i=result.length;i==0;i--)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
               result1[0]="Latest";

            }
            result1[i]=result[i-1];

        }
```

Comment: Add (or) replace, if add, consider using arraylist and at the end covert it to array?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: You need to

1. Create a new array with with size = old length + 1.
2. Copy the content of the old array to the new array,
3. Insert `"latest"` into the new array:

Like this:

```
String[] result = { "a", "b", "c" };
String[] tmp = new String[result.length+1];

System.arraycopy(result, 0, tmp, 1, result.length);
tmp[0] = "latest";
result = tmp;
```

But, I encourage you to consider using a `List` such as [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in which case you could express this as

```
result.add(0, "latest");
```

Comment: This is nice, but isn't arraylist will be faster and easy if allowed to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can't : an array has a fixed length.

If you want to have variable size "arrays", use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Exemple :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.set(0, "new a");
for (String s: list) {
    System.out(s);
}
```

Comment: can you give example of arraylist.

Comment: result1 = new String[result.length+1];
   
    for(int i=(result.length);i>=0;i--)
   {
    if(i==0)
    {
       result1[0]="Latest";
       
    }
    else
    {
     result1[i]=result[i-1];
    }
                  
              resultfinal=result1;
   }     */

Answer (score 0):

But you can use ArrayList and with  `add(int index, E object)` function you can add items wherever you want. And you can convert ArrayList to array[] easly

Answer (score 0):

Use stack which works as LIFO (Last In First Out), hence whenever you pop (read) you will get the latest(at the top) pushed item

Here is the Java code reference using Array: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Implementing_stack_operation_using_array_representation_with_java_program

Comment: how to add values in arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your solution is that when `i == 0`, you set the value to `Latest` but the value is overwritten after with  `result1[i]=result[i-1];`

Try

```
if(i==0) {
     result1[0]="Latest";
}
else {
     result1[i]=result[i-1];
}
```

Comment: Only the first item (index 0) will have `"Latest"`